# AWS - LB session cookie stickiness

Tags: amazon-web-services, session-cookies, aws-application-load-balancer

I am using an AWS `Application Load Balancer`. I have set the `session cookie stickiness` to **10 minutes**, however, when I check it from the browser, the **Expires/Max age** value is the **November 2071**.

What I am doing wrong in the stickiness configuration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

10 minutes is how long the load balancer will ensure that all your request go to a single target server. It is not how long the load balancer will track your session. The load balancer doesn't rely on cookie expiration in order to end the 10 minute "stickiness" period, it's using something internal to the load balancer to do that. The cookie just gives your browser a unique ID that the load balancer can use to identify you for its internal tracking needs.

Comment: Does that mean that it is not possible to change the cookie time on the web?

Comment: I don't know what "cookie time on the web" means.

Comment: I mean, the cookie max age I see in the browser, is not possible to reduce that time? instead of years, to 15 minutes for example?

Comment: No it's not possible